# NestJs + Typeorm, migration:generate returns Your schema is up to date - there are no queries to be executed by schema syncronization

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

Had an issue running:

```
ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:generate -n new_changes
```

I'm using env variables and my .env looks like this:

```
TYPEORM_PORT=
TYPEORM_CONNECTION=postgres
TYPEORM_DATABASE=XXX
TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS=src/migrations/*.ts
TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS_DIR=src/migrations
TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE=false
TYPEORM_USERNAME=postgres
TYPEORM_HOST=XXX
TYPEORM_PASSWORD=XXX
```

I'm trying to generate a new migration after adding a new table, and modifying some columns,
but I always get:

`Your schema is up to date - there are no queries to be executed by schema syncronization.`

Answer (score 1):

The fix for my issue was adding another env variable with the right reference to my entities:
`TYPEORM_ENTITIES=dist/**/*.entity.js`

*mind the .entity. suffix, only add it if you use this convention everywhere.

I'm using env variables, this also works with ormconfig.json,
`entities: ["dist/**/*.entity.js"],`

Also, please note that many other issues I've seen on stackoverflow that are similar (but not this case) was caused by:
`TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE=true`
If you synchronize the DB, changes update every time you run your nest app, the schema is updated and so there is nothing to generate.